# TypeError:_idex.default.onRegionChange is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

[I am building a react native application which has a map component, and a search component. The search and map component is rendered in the home component.
When a user types in a location the function 'getLangLong' which is available in the search component retrieves the new latitude and longitude and passes the new region through 'b.onRegionChange(region).
But I am getting an error the 'onRegionChange' is not a function.

**This is the error that I am getting.**

 [image: This is the error that I am getting.]

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text } from 'react-native';
import styles from './styles';
import TheMap from 'app/components/map';
import SearchBar from 'app/components/searchBar';

export default class Home extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TheMap />
        <SearchBar />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
     export default class TheMap extends Component{
     constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      region: {
       latitude: 45.492409,
      longitude: -73.582153,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421
    },
    };
  }

    onRegionChange(region){
    this.setState({ region });
    }
   
    render(){
    return (    
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView 
                onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
                region={this.state.region} 
                style={styles.mapStyle} />
        </View>
    );
}
}
 const b=new TheMap();
```

```js
  async getLatLong(prediction){
    //console.log(prediction);
    const key="MY_API_KEY";
    const geoUrl=`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=${key}&placeid=${prediction}`;
    
    try{
    const georesult= await fetch(geoUrl);
    const gjson= await georesult.json();
    this.setState({locations:gjson.result.geometry.location});
    this.setState({
      region:{
      latitude:this.state.locations.lat,
      longitude:this.state.locations.lng,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421
      }
      
    });
    b.onRegionChange(this.state.region);

    }
    catch(err){
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please add details about the execution environment (operating system, programming language, framework... etc.). From the first code snippet, please try to highlight the relevant parts.

Comment: I am building a react native application, I am running my code on expo cli.
In the first code snippet, " onRegionChange(region){ this.setState({ region }); } "
is used to change the region in the second component (the second code snippet is in the second component)

Comment: It will help if you can update the post with this very useful information.

Comment: I've removed your API key from your answer. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey